# Getting the identity key when inserting from DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
     UserID          int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,    UserName        varchar(50)
,    InsertDate      datetime2 DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

In Python, I want to insert into this table from a DataFrame and get back the `UserID` of the rows I just inserted

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(...)
df = pd.DataFrame({'UserName': ['Alice', 'Bob']})
df.to_sql('Users', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

The data is getting into the database. But how can I get back the `UserID` of the rows I just inserted? I considered writing a wrapper function that first insert into a temp table and use T-SQL to manipulate the data and return what I want. But is there a simpler way?

**Note**: I cannot modify the table's schema in anyway. I can only create temp tables in the database.

Comment: Have you found a more robust solution for this? I need the same functionality and would rather not upload THEN query for the primary keys of the section I just inserted.

Answer (score -6):

To get the data back.... you just need to query the table.

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    df=pd.read_sql("select * from Users",conn)
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question. It just gets every row in the table, not the ones I just inserted.

Comment: @Mike_Henderson modify the query to only retrieve the required data. 

If however there are going to be lots of data - you will need to add a non-primary index to the name columns else this will take a long time.